# List of ALL Excel Functions by Version

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a table somewhere showing all the Excel functions and the versions in which each is supported?  I'm trying to make sure I can share my 2010 worksheets with 2003 users, and don't want to use formulae that don't exist in early versions.  Microsoft pages don't seem to indicate when a formula was implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried searching, but I couldn't find any that consolidates all.

So I made one. Here's the link:

[Excel Functions: Compatibility Reference (2010, 2007 & 2003)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsHau4_IeCfwdG45c0VhcjBBUGNreVo2ZzNNRU1BT0E) via Google Spreadsheets

Sources:

- [Microsoft Office: Excel Functions
  (Alphabetical)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-alphabetical-HA010342655.aspx)
  -- 2010 list
- [Microsoft Office: Excel Functions (Alphabetical
  List)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-alphabetical-list-HA010277524.aspx)
  -- 2007 list
- [Microsoft Office: Excel Functions by
  Category](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx)
  -- 2003 list

Answer (score 3):

If you "save as", you can select 2003 format. Excel will then warn you of things that will not transfer (make sure you save first as 2010 type so you don't actually loose anything!). Even with the same file name, they wont overwrite each other as they will have different extensions. If it looses too much, all is not lost - you just have to get the compatibility pack from MS Office downloads and get everyone with 2003 to install it (it's free).

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3

---

Install this compatibility pack if you would like to open, edit, and save documents, workbooks, and presentations that were created in the newer versions of Word, Excel, and PowerPoint. Scroll down to see instructions and system requirements.

Users of the Microsoft Office XP and 2003 programs Word, Excel, or PowerPoint—please install all High-Priority updates from Microsoft Update before downloading the Compatibility Pack.

By installing the Compatibility Pack in addition to Microsoft Office 2000, Office XP, or Office 2003, you will be able to open, edit, and save files using the file formats in newer versions of Word, Excel, and PowerPoint .

The Compatibility Pack can also be used in conjunction with the Microsoft Office Word Viewer 2003, Excel Viewer 2003, and PowerPoint Viewer 2003 to view files saved in these new formats. For more information about the Compatibility Pack, see 924074.

---

Answer (score 2):

The best I can find is that Microsoft have a list of the functions in [Excel 2003](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx) - If you don't see it here, don't use it.