# Excel - Formula Based Individual Durations and Total Duration Calculation from Slash-Separated Time-Strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to calculate (using worksheet formula based solution only) individual time-durations and total time duration from the slash '/' separated time-texts in two cells (each value of first cell are time-from and corresponding values in the second cell are time-to)  in Excel (still using Excel 2007 only)

Input cells (B1 contains times-from data, however B2 contains corresponding times-to data)

```
Cell-B1:  "00:20 / 00:58 / 09:25 / 12:05 / 17:26 / 21:58"
Cell-B2:  "00:45 / 07:57 / 11:41 / 15:57 / 21:27 / 23:48"
```

Expected Output (B6 to show individual time duration, and cell B7 to show grand total of all durations)

```
Cell-B6:  "00:25 / 06:59 / 02:16 / 03:52 / 04:01 / 01:50"
Cell-B7:  19:23:00
```

The data organized and expected output results are as shown in below snapshot image.

[SNAPSHOT IMG: View my input data cells, and expected output data cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PJ2i.png)

I understand, VBA can do it easily and I do have basic VBA knowledge, however is there a possible single formula (may or may not be array formula) based solution to show individual time-duration and sum of the all the calculated time-duration? I simply want to avoid VBA Macros and also do not want manual process of Text To Column (using delimiter '/') then do individual time-duration calculation, and then finally show all the duration in joined form, and show the grand total of all individual time-durations.

To arrive the results, only few basic worksheet functions may only be used such as MID, FIND, SUM, SEARCH, TRIM, SUBSTITUTE, INDEX, ROW etc.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser. Please note that this is not a free code writing service. That said, if you could show us what you have tried so far and explain the problem with it, we can take a look and help out

Comment: Hi, I have googled to find answer using of similar question, I at a time find a formula
=SUM(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), (ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*LEN(A1)+1, LEN(A1)))))
which sums up comma-separated values in a single-cell value
Example: in a single-cell comma-separated value is entered as: 26, 13, 7, 22, 25
and using above formula it sums up the values.

Hence, I think there must be a similar solution for this too.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the formula to suit your needs?

Comment: Hi,
I am able to access individual values entered in the slash '/' separated values in two cells, but do not know how to do mathematical operation (like finding differences, one by one) and sum up all answers.

Values-in-1st-Cell Array-Formula = VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",""))+1))-1)*LEN(B1)+1,LEN(B1))))

Values-in-2nd-Cell: Array-Formula = VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",""))+1))-1)*LEN(B2)+1,LEN(B2))))

Comment: Yes I have tried and modified to get results. Here is the so called discovered and modified  worksheet formula, it gives the nearly result that I want but cant understand how. Could anyone please explain functionality of it, and correct the formula: 
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",""))+1))-1)*LEN(B2)+1,LEN(B2))))-VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",""))+1))-1)*LEN(B1)+1,LEN(B1)))),"[hh]:mm:ss")&" / ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [your formula](https://superuser.com/questions/1780820/excel-formula-based-individual-durations-and-total-duration-calculation-from-s/1780870#comment2780288_1780820) to SUM differences

```
=TEXT(SUM(
   VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B2))),
      (ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",""))+1))-1)*
      LEN(B2)+1,LEN(B2))))-
   VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),
      (ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",""))+1))-1)*
      LEN(B1)+1,LEN(B1))))), "hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Formula

Sorry, saw the requirements to exclude any of the functionality that makes this easy ;-)  Maybe leave this up for someone using a current version of Excel that stumbles on it.

```
=LET(
   durations, MAP(TEXTSPLIT(B1," / "),TEXTSPLIT(B2," / "),
      LAMBDA(from,to,TIMEVALUE(to)-TIMEVALUE(from))),
   VSTACK(
      TEXTJOIN(" / ",FALSE,BYCOL(durations,LAMBDA(dur,TEXT(dur,"hh:mm")))),
      TEXT(SUM(durations), "hh:mm")))
```

1. The [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function is used to enable naming/storing intermediate calculations for later use
2. [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) **"from"** and **"to"** strings on **`" \ "`** and [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) values into the [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function's **`from`** and **`to`** variables
3. [LAMBDA's](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) formula uses [TIMEVALUE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/timevalue-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645) to convert the mapped strings and returns the difference of each mapped pair as a column in a one-row array named **`durations`**
4. [VSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) is used to return a 2-row (1-column) array:

   - **Row 1:**  [TEXJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) concatenates **`durations'`** values delimited by **`" / "`** after first applying the [TEXT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) format **`"hh:mm"`** via another [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function
   - **Row 2:**  [TEXT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) format **`"hh:mm"`** is applied to the [SUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89) of **`durations'`** values.

[image]

Comment: Above answer is also correct, however it may not work in Excel 2007 and resulting with #Name error

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I belatedly recognized that and added a note to the answer.   There isn't much in it that will not break in Excel 2007.  Not much use to you but left it up for future searchers who have more recent versions.

Comment: In trying to figure out the options, I found a link to this spreadsheet [Excel Functions: Compatibility Reference (2010, 2007 & 2003](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsHau4_IeCfwdG45c0VhcjBBUGNreVo2ZzNNRU1BT0E) in this 2012  Stack Exchange [answer by Ellesa](https://superuser.com/a/440400/)